# Clearing cookie on logout and session expiration

Tags: logout, session, cookies

I would like to clear the session cookie when a user logs out or when their session expires. I understand that [`wp_clear_auth_cookie();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_clear_auth_cookie) clears the cookie but I am struggling to understand how to implement it. I am using the following code to log a user out automatically if they are inactive for 10 minutes. (I think I found that in here too)

```
function myplugin_cookie_expiration( $expiration, $user_id, $remember ) {
    return $remember ? $expiration : 600;
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'myplugin_cookie_expiration', 99, 3 );
```

Could someone kindly direct me to the right direction to achieve this result?

Comment: Maybe I got you wrong, but isn't that exactly what WP does when the current user is about to log out? Clearing the cookie, that is.

Comment: It only works if the user closes the browser and reopens it. If not it uses the same authentication cookie. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `$experation` to a negative integer:

```
function myplugin_cookie_expiration( $expiration, $user_id, $remember ) {
    return $remember ? $expiration : -600;
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'myplugin_cookie_expiration', 99, 3 );
```

From the w3schools PHP page on cookies:

```
<?php
// set the expiration date to one hour ago
setcookie("user", "", time()-3600);
?>
```